# Div not showing from echo php

Tags: php

I'm having another problem with this code. I have tried different ways but no success.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
 if($fgmembersite->ChangePassword()){
    echo '<div id="ajaxDivOk">Password alterada com sucesso</div>'; 
    sleep(2);
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("index.php");
 }
 echo '<div id="ajaxDivErro">A mudança de password não foi efetuadada....tente mais tarde</div>';
 sleep(2);
}
```

In the debugger, I get the `echo`...but not in the main page.

This is my main page:

```
<?PHP
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
if (!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin()) {
    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("index.php");
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
     if($fgmembersite->ChangePassword()){
        echo '<div id="ajaxDivOk">Password alterada com sucesso</div>'; 
        sleep(2);
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("index.php");
     }
     echo '<div id="ajaxDivErro">A mudança de password não foi efetuadada....tente mais tarde</div>';
     sleep(2);
}

$email = $fgmembersite->UserEmail();
?>
<html>
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>EBSPMA Atividades</title>
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/modernizr.js?cb=2.2.3.2085"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header role="banner" class="main-header">
            <!-- MAIN HEADER -->
            <div class="main-header-body">
                <div class="container-wrapper">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <h2>EBSPMA PAAD</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-1 main-header-title">
                                <p class="sizeToggle" >Mudar Password</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header><section class="content">
            <div class="grid">
                <div class="box">
                    <form name="changepwd" id="loginForm" action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name='submitted' id='submitted'/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="path" value="painelAdquirente.action"/>
                        <div>
                            <p><b><font color="red">A sua password deve ser alterada!</font></b></p></div>
                        <div class="icon-input">
                            <label for="password"></label>
                            <div class="input password">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                <input type="password" name="oldpwd" id="oldpwd" placeholder="Senha antiga">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div class="icon-input">
                            <label for="password"></label>
                            <div class="input password">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                <input type="password" name="newpwd" id="newpwd" placeholder="Senha nova">
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" id="sbmtLogin" class="sa-btn1" value="Mudar">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">     
                    <div id="ajaxDivOk" style="display:none" class="alert alert-success">Aqui</div> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div id="ajaxDivErro"  style="display:none" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js?cb=2.2.3.2085"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The function is working since I receive in my debugger the sentence

```
<div class="alert alert-success">Verifique o seu mail....Obrigado</div>
```

So what's wrong?

UPDATE:

I'm still having a problem: now I have this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: checkMudaPass is not defined

The function is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">           
            function checkMudaPass(){
                var res = "<?php echo $result; ?>";
                console.log(res);
                if(res === "1"){
                    document.getElementById('ajaxDivOk').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('ajaxDivOk').innerHTML = "A mudança de password foi efetuada....Verifique o seu email";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById('ajaxDivErro').style.display = "block";
                    document.getElementById('ajaxDivErro').innerHTML = "A mudança de password não foi efetuada";
                }
               setTimeout(function(){
                    window.location='index.php';
                 }, 5000); 
            };   
        </script>


 <input type="submit" id="submitted"  name="submitted" class="sa-btn1" value="Mudar" onclick="checkMudaPass()">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry...don't get your point

Comment: You need to understand the page request cycle - before the browser displays anything, the server has to finish sending the data. So instead of displaying your message for 2 seconds, then redirecting, all that happens is the redirect is delayed. If you must show a message then redirect, you need to handle the redirect client side, eg with javascript

Comment: I mean that you should create a minimal, verifiable example of your problem (like described in the link) instead of posting a huge wall of code where the majority of it is totally irrelevant to the problem and expecting others to analyse it. It helps yourself to understand what's going on, and increases the chances of actually getting an answer.